# itextsharp for 64 bit operating system

Tags: c#, itext

I am developing an application using visual studio on a 64 bit Windows 7 OS . 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ has a library for a 32 bit OS , but not a 64 bit .

Any suggestions on where could I find a 64 bit library ?

Comment: I think you can still use 32 bit ITextSharp.dll on 64 bit Windows 7

Comment: how to do that.. more details please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a 64bit download either, but you can download the source and do a 64 bit build your self. Here is the url for getting the source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/develop